# Dedup variable keeping max or min in specific variable on dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

for example, I want to dedup an ID and it keep the maximum or minimum depending on variable that I want to specify. Can I do that using some function in pandas?
Data is as dataframe. The drop_duplicate() don't help because It doesn't keep the value that I want, just by order.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'ID': ['245', '144', '245', '245', '144'],
'Acesso': [3, 1, 1, 5, 2],
'Number': [4, 4, 2, 2, 5]
})
```

[image]

I want an output like a picture, keeping the minimum in "Acesso"  and maximum in "Number", deduplicated "ID".

[image]

Comment: Provide minimal reproducible code and sample data and show us your desired output as well. also avoid screenshots for data/code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by separately taking the `min` of `Acesso` grouped by `ID` and the `max` of `Number` grouped by `ID`.

You then just have to concatenate these into a single DataFrame. The code would look like this:

```py
df_acesso_min = df.groupby("ID")["Acesso"].min()
df_number_max = df.groupby("ID")["Number"].max()

df = pd.concat([df_acesso_min, df_number_max], axis=1)

print(df)
#      Acesso  Number
# ID
# 144       1       5
# 245       1       4
```